# SSRS - Line chart label influenced by seperate custom code?

Tags: reporting-services

I have encountered a really weird bug?? in SSRS as I try to implement a line chart with only the last data label. The chart displays predictive linear regression measures and I have implemented a custom code function in the code-behind that determines the color of the "predictive" line (based upon a lookupset which determines if the trend is up or down). I want to have conditional logic that so that only the last point on the line is shown in the label which is usually not a big problem but this time I'm running into issues. As soon as I call the custom code function to determine line color, the last point on my line shows the second last point's field value.  If staticly set the line to have a color of "Red", then the last point has it's own field value as the data label.

This would be much easier to explain if I could post my screenshots, but I'll try to layout a scenario if clarification is needed:

Scenario 1) Line color determined in code-behind
Formulas in report:

1. **Line data label**: Trim(Fields!Month.Value)
2. **Category label**:  Trim(Fields!Month.Value)
3. **Line color**: Code.TrendDirection(LookupSet(1, Fields!Lookup.Value, Fields!MonthTrend.Value, "FacilityTrends"))

Values for last data point:

1. **Line data label**: Mar-2014
2. **Category label**: Apr-2014
3. **Line color**: Red (as properly determined by code behind)

Scenario 2) Line color set statically

Formulas in report:

1. **Line data label**: Trim(Fields!Month.Value)
2. **Category label**:  Trim(Fields!Month.Value)
3. **Line color**: *"Red"*

Values for last data point:

1. **Line data label**: *Apr*-2014
2. **Category label**: Apr-2014
3. **Line color**: Red

Why would the custom code expression for line color affect the field value of the last line data point? Any ideas?